# How do I display/update a tweet from a designated hashtag every 30 seconds

Tags: php, api, twitter, hashtag

I have a php webpage where the user selects a Twitter hashtag.

Using the Twitter API I'd like to then display the most current tweet for that hashtag and update this every 30 seconds.

Any support on this would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search), a sample url, content encoded with `json`:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23TAG&rpp=1

Replace **TAG** with your Tag, **%23** = #. **rpp=1** means return only one tweet (results_per_page).

Now with `json_decode();` and a bit of code you can output the newest Tweet. For the refresh use Javascript or redirect the page to itself every 30 second..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an Ajax Request for that because that will be a better experience to the user. For timed operations there are methods in many Ajax Frameworks. For Example in Prototype you could use http://www.prototypejs.org/api/timedObserver

The only way you can do it in plain PHP is refreshing the site (by redirecting to itsself) every 30 seconds which does not have a good feel to the user.